# can only be default-imported using the 'allowsyntheticdefaultimports'

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, types

How can I fix this?
Can only be default-imported using the 'allowsyntheticdefaultimports' flag
[image: See screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

You can write 'import * from ' to replace 'import firebase from';

or add an config in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```